# find angle at line-circle intersection

Tags: geometry

I have a ray $a$ starting at point $P$ (defined by the coordinates $d_h$,$d_v$) that intersect with a circle at point $S$ (defined by the coordinates $b_h$,$b_v$). How can I calculate angle $\beta$?

### Given

*(everything that's blue in the sketch)*

- a circle located at the point of origin with a radius $r_w$, where $r_w > 0$
- starting point $P(d_h,d_v)$ of the ray $a$, where $d_h \ge r_w$ and $d_h \ge 0$
- angle $\alpha$ of the ray $a$, where $0° \lt \alpha \lt 90°$

### Wanted

- angle $\beta$ in ° between the horizontal point of origin and the line going from the point of origin to point $S$

[image: problem sketch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve quadratic equation.

Circle:

$$x^2+y^2 = r_w^2$$

Line:

$$y = \tan(\pi-\alpha) (x+d_h) + d_v$$

Combine the two, solve, and pick the solution which is closer to the source.

Good luck!

Comment: $x = b_h$ and $y = b_v$, correct?

Comment: @bitbonk Yep ;-)

Comment: To get $\beta$ I can use $sin(\beta)=b_v/r_w$. But to get $b_v$, I need $b_h$. I don't see a way to get rid of $b_h$ and $b_v$ by combining the two equations you mentioned.

Comment: This is what I got so far: $z=tan(\pi-\alpha)$ and $r_w^2=b_h^2+z^2b_h^2+z^22b_hd_h+z^2d_h^2+2zb_h+2zd_h+d_v^2$

Comment: @bitbonk Substitute the second equation into the $y$ in the first and you get $Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0$. Solve for $x$, and use the second to calculate $y$ from $x$ you got.

Comment: How did you find that second equation in the first place?

Comment: @bitbonk It's just an equation for a line passing through $(-d_h,d_v)$ and angled $\tan(\pi - \alpha)$. Check out the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation).

Comment: I still can't connect the dots between that wikipedia page and your equation. That page is about linear equations which by its nature are endless lines. Can you give me one more hint? ;)

Comment: @bitbonk What is the equation for an endless line that goes through point $P$ and is angled $\tan(\pi-\alpha)$ (in other words it goes through $P$ and $S$ in your picture)?

Comment: If I use the *Two-point form* from that wikipedia page $$y-y_1=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)$$ I get this: $$y=\frac{b_v-d_v}{b_h-d_h}(x-d_h)+d_v$$ I can replace replace $\frac{b_v-d_v}{b_h-d_h}$ with $tan(\pi-\alpha)$ but there is still a difference to your equation left: $(x+d_h)$ vs. $(x-d_h)$

Comment: @bitbonk The coordinates of $P$ are $(-d_h,d_v)$, not $(d_h, d_v)$.

Comment: The coordnate system in my image is horizontally mirrored. Every x on the left side of the center of the circle is positive. If we stick with your interpretation then the coordinates, $S$ also needs to be $(-bh,bv)$.

Comment: @bitbonk Yes, indeed. So $y = -b_h$ contrary to my agreement in the second comment.

Comment: Thank you for your patience! I think all dots are connected now. It's been a long time since high school ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tried combining and transforming the equations as @dtldarek mentioned. It's just hard to verify that I didn't make a mistake:

$r_w^2=x^2+(tan(\pi-\alpha)(x+d_h)+d_v)^2$

$r_w^2=x^2+(tan(\pi-\alpha)(x+d_h))^2+2tan(\pi-\alpha)(x+d_h)d_v+d_v^2$

$k=tan(\pi-\alpha)$

$r_w^2=x^2+(k(x+d_h))^2+2k(x+d_h)d_v+d_v^2$

$r_w^2=x^2+(kx+kd_h)^2+2kd_vx+2kd_vd_h+d_v^2$

$r_w^2=x^2+(kx)^2+2k^2d_hx+(kd_h)^2+2kd_vx+2kd_vd_h+d_v^2$

$r_w^2=x^2+k^2x^2+2k^2d_hx+(kd_h)^2+2kd_vx+2kd_vd_h+d_v^2$

$r_w^2=(1+k^2)x^2+2k^2d_hx+(kd_h)^2+2kd_vx+2kd_vd_h+d_v^2$

$r_w^2=(1+k^2)x^2+(2k^2d_h+2kd_v)x+(kd_h)^2+2kd_vd_h+d_v^2$

$0=(1+k^2)x^2+(2k^2d_h+2kd_v)x+(kd_h)^2+2kd_vd_h+d_v^2-r_w^2$

$0=Ax^2+Bx+C$

$A=1+k^2=1+(tan(\pi-\alpha))^2$

$B=2k^2d_h+2kd_v=2(tan(\pi-\alpha))^2d_h+2(tan(\pi-\alpha))d_v$

$C=(kd_h)^2+2kd_vd_h+d_v^2-r_w^2=(tan(\pi-\alpha)d_h)^2+2tan(\pi-\alpha)d_vd_h+d_v^2-r_w^2$

Comment: I got $A = 1+k^2$, $B = 2k^2d_h + 2kd_v$ and $C = k^2d_h^2 + 2kd_hd_v +d_v^2 - r^2$, so I think you need to check $A$ (I think you make a mistake between 8th and 9th line, i.e. $x^2 + (kx)^2 = (1+k^2)x^2 \neq 2k^2x^2$). [This is a nice tools for _checking_](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+%2B+%28k*%28x%2Bh%29%2Bv%29%5E2+-r%5E2) (it is better to try to solve by hand first).